How do I disable HTTP OPTIONS method for a static website hosted in a GCP bucket?
I have a static website hosted in a GCP bucket with an external Application Load Balancer to route the traffic. And I need to disable the HTTP OPTIONS method based on the advice from a vulnerability scanning report, saying that these HTTP methods (TRACE, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT and CONNECT) should not be enabled unless necessary. This means that when a client sends a request with HTTP OPTIONS verb it should get "405 Method Not Allowed" response.
The website itself is a static website built with Flutter web and per my understanding it is not straightforward to do the blocking inside the Flutter application.
With some researches it looks that I can create a Cloud Armor policy that matches request.method=='OPTIONS' and performs the Deny action.
However based on the security policy document, the Layer 7 filtering is not supported for the Edge security policy type. When I actually applied such Cloud Armor policy to my backend bucket, GCP pops an alert saying that this is not supported (just likes what the document said).

Define what you mean by block. What do you expect the browser to do if you block the OPTIONS request? Have you instead considered correctly configuring CORS for Google Cloud Storage? Note: I am unaware of any security compliance requirement that recommends blocking the OPTIONS request. Edit your post with more information.

As per the enclosed GCP official doc, you are correct! Cloud Armor Edge security policies do not currently support Layer 7 filtering like blocking specific HTTP methods. Try this alternative approach (Use an HTTP Proxy Server) to achieve your goal of blocking HTTP OPTIONS requests for your static website:  (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/community/blob/master/archived/cloud-run-golang-gcs-proxy/index.md)

One option to consider is using Cloud Armor's backend security policy to invoke the method block and then use an Internet Network Endpoint Group (NEG) using the FQDN value to the GCS bucket rather than the backendBuckets option on your Application Load Balancer. You would setup a backendService that leverages an Internet NEG and then you access GCS that way. Since you are using an Internet NEG, you can apply the Cloud Armor backend security policy.

I will give it a try.
